# Replace underscores on typing number input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input, frontend, imaskjs

I have a text field with little underscores as `(_________)`. How do I use JavaScript to make these dashes to be replaced by the input number upon typing? `(48721____)` As I type, I want the underscore to be replaced with the number I type. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const p = document.querySelector("p")
const amountOfDashes = 10
p.textContent = "_".padEnd(amountOfDashes, "_")
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if(e.key === "Backspace") {
        const pattern = /\d(?!\d)/;
        if(!pattern.test(p.textContent)) return;
        p.textContent = p.textContent.replace(pattern, "_");
        return;
    }
    const val = parseInt(e.key);
    if(isNaN(val)) return;
    p.textContent = p.textContent.replace("_", val);
})
```

Tell me if this solves your problem.

Comment: but when you delete it, it doesn't delete it and replace again underscore.

Comment: I edited the code as you asked but i think you should use input element

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more of a CSS/HTML problem than a javascript problem.

For insertion you can use javascript like this

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
var s = this.selectionStart;
this.value = this.value.substr(0, s) + this.value.substr(s + 1);
this.selectionEnd = s;
}, false);
```

Here is a working example https://codepen.io/jteck13/pen/RwYoeMp

Hope I could help